# Rails: Better way to write test case for concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have following code in concern:

```
module UserStatus
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  included do
    enum status: %i[not_started in_progress completed]
  end
end
```

I am trying to write an rspec test for it.

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'user_status' do
  it 'test' do
    byebug
    should define_enum_for(:status).with(%i[not_started in_progress completed])
  end
end
```

The above case returns an error:

```
undefined method `defined_enums' for Module:Class
```

If I remove `should`, it passes. But I don't know if that's the right way to test it. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The word `should` does not go there. Your specs ought to look more like this:

```
RSpec.describe 'user_status' do
  it 'should do something related to the user_status' do
    define_enum_for(:status).with(%i[not_started in_progress completed])
  end
end
```

When written in this way your specs are telling the story of what they are doing. The `should do something` bit of text is the plain-English description of what the spec is testing and the code that comes after it is the actual Ruby code that makes up the test.

The "plain-English" portion of the spec is solely so you can understand what that spec is meant to do, and the use of the word "should" is only to help you understand it. You can write anything at all there and it will not impact the actual spec. Another way of writing it might be:

```
it 'ensures the user_status is valid' do
  <whatever your ruby code is>
end
```

Or:

```
it 'renders the user_status view' do
  <whatever your ruby code is>
end
```

The point is, make the plain-English text line up with what the spec is doing so that in the future you can come back to that spec and know instantly what it is testing without having to decipher the Ruby code.

Comment: `it { should define_enum_for(:status) }` is a [correct syntax](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/blob/master/lib/shoulda/matchers/active_record/define_enum_for_matcher.rb) for shoulda_matchers

Answer (score 0):

You can't test the module, you need to test the model itself. So you need to add

```
it { should define_enum_for(:status).with(%i[not_started in_progress completed]) }
```

to the model specs.

If you don't want to repeat this line in every model which includes the concern, you can write [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples)

```
# it is convenient to write in the separate file, e.g. 'spec/support/models/shared_examples_for_statusable.rb'
RSpec.shared_examples 'status_able' do 
  it { should define_enum_for(:status).with(%i[not_started in_progress completed]) }
end

require '/support/models/shared_examples_for_statusable.rb'
RSpec.describe SomeClass do
  it_behaves_like 'status_able'
end
```